# Generate CMS with Secure Element Chip, understanding the way a CMS signature is generated (signed data with signer infos and signed attributes)

Tags: python, pki, csr, pkcs#7

We have a testsuite written in python and I have to add tests using a PKI. For a certificate enrollment I have to put an CSR and the manufacture certificate in a CMS and send it to the PKI.

With openssl I can do it with:

```
openssl smime -sign -outform PEM -signer manufacture.crt -inkey DMC.key -in CSR.pem -binary -nodetach -out CMS.p7
```

In this case, my keys are genereated with openssl. But we have to use a hardware secure element to generate the keys and calculate the signature.
Until now I can create the same CMS structure with python, but I cannot verify it with openssl:

```
openssl cms -verify -noverify -inform PEM -in python_generated_cms.txt
```

The result is "Verification failure". But when I add the option **-nosigs**, then the optput is my CSR. So my signature seems to be invalid. I have studied [rfc5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652) but without success.

Here is my workflow to calulate the signature:

1. According to [chapter 11.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-11.2) the message digest is the PEM encoded
   CSR digedsted with the digest algorithm.
2. Then [chapter 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.4) says
   if signedAttrs are present, the input of the signature calculation
   is the complete DER endoced value of the SignedAttrs. So I take the
   complete binary representation of the content of signedAttrs (marked
   with a * in the section below).
3. I change the "IMPLICIT tag" [0] to a
   "EXPLICIT SET OF" by changing the first byte form 0xA0 to 0x31
4. Hash this data with the algorithm corresponding the algorithm of my
   hardeware secure element (SHA384).
5. Send this hash to the seucre element to calulate the signature.
6. The signature consists of 48 Bytes each r and s part will be packed in a ans1 signature beginning with 0x30, 0x64 and this will be added as the signature to the signer infos

---

Following my parsed CMS as an example:

```
SEQUENCE (2 elem)
  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.7.2 signedData (PKCS #7)
  [0] (1 elem)
    SEQUENCE (5 elem)
      INTEGER 1
      SET (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
          NULL
      SEQUENCE (2 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 data (PKCS #7)
        [0] (1 elem)
          OCTET STRING (416 byte) 2D2D2D2D2D424547494E20434554553542D2D2D2D2…        [CMS]
      [0] (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (3 elem)
          
                ... shorted certificate here ...

          SEQUENCE (1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.4.3.3 ecdsaWithSHA384 (ANSI X9.62 ECDSA algorithm with SHA384)
          BIT STRING (1 elem)
            SEQUENCE (2 elem)
              INTEGER (384 bit) 251806783159843676750320964557058746…
              INTEGER (383 bit) 146223079633757899471433693312235433…
      SET (1 elem)
        SEQUENCE (6 elem)
          INTEGER 1
          SEQUENCE (2 elem)
            SEQUENCE (4 elem)
              SET (1 elem)
                SEQUENCE (2 elem)
                  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.6 countryName (X.520 DN component)
                  PrintableString CH
              SET (1 elem)
                SEQUENCE (2 elem)
                  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.10 organizationName (X.520 DN component)
                  PrintableString My organisation
              SET (1 elem)
                SEQUENCE (2 elem)
                  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.11 organizationalUnitName (X.520 DN component)
                  PrintableString PKI
              SET (1 elem)
                SEQUENCE (2 elem)
                  OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.5.4.3 commonName (X.520 DN component)
                  PrintableString Non-Prod CA
            INTEGER (82 bit) 3419130548216348442042883485
          SEQUENCE (2 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1 sha-256 (NIST Algorithm)
            NULL
*         [0] (4 elem)
*           SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*             OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.3 contentType (PKCS #9)
*             SET (1 elem)
*               OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.7.1 data (PKCS #7)
*           SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*             OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.5 signingTime (PKCS #9)
*             SET (1 elem)
*               UTCTime 2020-06-26 07:13:41 UTC
*           SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*             OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.4 messageDigest (PKCS #9)
*             SET (1 elem)
*               OCTET STRING (32 byte) 6558254059E939DF800A748CCF2F582371AC1…     [message digest]
*           SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*             OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.1.9.15 sMIMECapabilities
*             SET (1 elem)
*               SEQUENCE (8 elem)
*                 SEQUENCE (1 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.42 aes256-CBC (NIST Algorithm)
*                 SEQUENCE (1 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.22 aes192-CBC (NIST Algorithm)
*                 SEQUENCE (1 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 2.16.840.1.101.3.4.1.2 aes128-CBC (NIST Algorithm)
*                 SEQUENCE (1 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.3.7 des-EDE3-CBC (RSADSI encryptionAlgorithm)
*                 SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.3.2 rc2CBC (RSADSI encryptionAlgorithm)
*                   INTEGER 128
*                 SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.3.2 rc2CBC (RSADSI encryptionAlgorithm)
*                   INTEGER 64
*                 SEQUENCE (1 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.3.14.3.2.7 desCBC
*                 SEQUENCE (2 elem)
*                   OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.113549.3.2 rc2CBC (RSADSI encryptionAlgorithm)
*                   INTEGER 40
          SEQUENCE (1 elem)
            OBJECT IDENTIFIER 1.2.840.10045.4.3.2 ecdsaWithSHA256 (ANSI X9.62 ECDSA algorithm with SHA256)
          OCTET STRING (1 elem)
            SEQUENCE (2 elem)
              INTEGER (384 bit) 37299296495250608665729486640423992…
              INTEGER (383 bit) 16047350112473148250997959352782288…
```

What am I doing wrong while calculating the signature of my CMS?

Comment: After further invistigations, the SignedAttrs fields are exactly the same like the working one from OpenSSL. The only difference is now the signature...

Answer (score 1):

The trick is that the signature is not only calculated over the SHA hash, but the hash has to be packed into an ASN.1 sequence before calculation of the signature. Please also have a look on the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63907540/manually-created-signature-in-certificate-signing-request-is-not-matching-with-t). [@Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63902570?noredirect=1) did a good Job on explaining it.