# How to manually calculate and verify the signature of a certificate signing request

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, public-key, pki

- I have created a keypair

`openssl genrsa -out test1 2048`

- then created a certificate signing request using that key

`openssl req -new -key test1 -subj "/CN=foo" -out foo.csr`

- verifying that certificate using `openssl req -in foo.csr -text`

  - It Contains the public key of the keypair i have generated

    ```
          Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
          Public-Key: (2048 bit)
          Modulus:
              00:ca:c5:29:98:08:05:30:30:03:08:eb:23:c2:af:
              3e:2e:2d:dc:11:96:cb:2f:d1:1f:7f:41:a4:00:13:
              8a:ee:4b:36:5b:f2:c1:d1:0f:8b:27:11:34:08:bd:
              4d:df:7e:6d:7a:d7:f9:dd:ea:62:ad:fa:8f:8c:eb:
              47:5f:55:82:2c:13:c2:11:41:12:b9:87:0b:3d:08:
              86:1b:ad:71:16:89:1c:fa:07:4a:86:8f:80:a9:99:
              37:f7:e2:d4:d3:d8:b2:5f:7f:c9:05:51:73:f0:c8:
              59:ec:c3:09:a2:03:a5:6e:ec:8b:d9:9c:11:de:d3:
              df:55:a5:3f:0c:36:d6:93:8a:70:a0:b9:61:cd:c9:
              4a:09:ad:f7:3e:fd:ce:6f:5c:bb:00:69:e9:3b:3d:
              85:3b:01:1d:8f:6a:a7:d4:61:f9:b5:07:1e:90:ed:
              ab:3b:41:cc:db:e8:a0:e7:88:b7:77:35:66:30:b7:
              a6:cd:ea:d6:12:f5:ef:82:63:e9:46:29:2e:7c:10:
              0e:32:fd:04:2d:cd:62:0e:4b:74:46:f7:fd:f6:4a:
              8d:fb:82:9d:37:11:50:ea:9f:f0:d6:64:2b:50:a4:
              f0:18:6e:81:28:11:04:db:2a:0a:f7:b1:70:c5:78:
              fe:ed:e3:55:2c:64:f4:a5:a0:96:f5:11:3a:27:2c:
              5a:51
          Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    ```
  - Subject attributes i have provided while creating the CSR

    ```
            Subject: CN=foo
    ```
  - Digital Signature Information

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    92:b0:82:a5:aa:98:4a:62:5a:84:8a:15:5c:6f:48:dc:e3:ec:
    7f:d5:04:e8:c1:47:55:3c:b3:57:84:16:ff:5a:0d:29:2c:16:
    f2:cc:0c:18:c3:1f:d5:e1:57:3a:dd:8b:b1:c6:92:c3:fe:cb:
    2b:9d:7d:79:d5:64:eb:31:00:8b:5e:77:48:ce:66:6f:dd:7b:
    71:41:f9:aa:6e:ea:ea:59:e0:cd:f8:db:a9:13:18:d2:2a:fc:
    12:25:b3:01:44:0c:b1:02:f7:1a:0f:d0:07:04:1d:9f:6f:a1:
    58:91:87:25:4a:d6:47:a6:b5:4e:3c:a1:fd:b6:6c:c3:96:16:
    c1:ab:00:d2:4c:95:ee:2c:01:2d:cf:0e:d0:62:1b:4f:0e:34:
    e3:e8:85:50:63:74:eb:1f:ac:95:30:d4:df:43:7f:58:11:90:
    35:29:9d:85:94:dc:c8:c2:29:81:46:71:20:62:9c:9c:f8:ef:
    ed:bc:8b:e3:d5:41:b3:14:f7:43:c6:b2:74:c2:22:06:a2:af:
    88:68:2e:67:c4:de:ed:61:37:41:d6:df:8a:76:7d:42:5d:98:
    d3:c9:19:8b:1d:26:73:92:95:0f:ba:c1:78:3a:55:87:e0:3e:
    16:13:34:6e:21:13:b9:da:b8:66:f3:0a:ec:79:ae:1a:95:6c:
    04:cf:b8:b5

Following are my doubts :

1. what all data fields it has considered to calculate the signature ?
2. can we manually create the signature and verify it with the one mentioned in CSR ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data over which the signature is calculated is pretty much everything in the CSR except for the signature algorithm and signature. This is called the `certificationRequestInfo` in [RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986#page-5).

The second question: how do we verify the signature?

**The short answer**: have `openssl` do it for you.

The easiest way by far is to ask `openssl` itself to verify it:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out test.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key test.key -subj "/CN=foo" -out foo.csr
$ openssl req -in foo.csr -verify -noout
verify OK
```

Done!

---

**The long (and tedious) answer**: do it manually

Ok, so you really want to do it manually. Let's give it a shot.

Given the above, we first need to extract the desired information from the CSR. Dumping the ASN.1 structure, we get:

```
$ openssl asn1parse -i -in foo.csr 
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 595 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=4 l= 315 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    8:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim:   INTEGER           :00
   11:d=2  hl=2 l=  14 cons:   SEQUENCE          
   13:d=3  hl=2 l=  12 cons:    SET               
   15:d=4  hl=2 l=  10 cons:     SEQUENCE          
   17:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      OBJECT            :commonName
   22:d=5  hl=2 l=   3 prim:      UTF8STRING        :foo
   27:d=2  hl=4 l= 290 cons:   SEQUENCE          
   31:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons:    SEQUENCE          
   33:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   44:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim:     NULL              
   46:d=3  hl=4 l= 271 prim:    BIT STRING        
  321:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 cons:   cont [ 0 ]        
  323:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
  325:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
  336:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
  338:d=1  hl=4 l= 257 prim:  BIT STRING
```

This is a structured CertificationRequest defined by [RFC 2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986#page-7) as:

```
CertificationRequest ::= SEQUENCE {
    certificationRequestInfo CertificationRequestInfo,
    signatureAlgorithm       AlgorithmIdentifier{{ SignatureAlgorithms }},
    signature                BIT STRING
}
```

The `certificationRequestInfo` (see RFC for structure details) in DER-encoded ASN.1 format is signed using the algorithm described in `signatureAlgorithm` and the private key to yield `signature`.

---

Let's extract all the parts we need from the CSR. The `strparse` value is the offset you want to export, this is the first number on each line in the output above.

```
# Extract the certificationRequestInfo (data to be signed)
$ openssl asn1parse -in foo.csr -strparse 4 -out info.der

# Extract the public key.
$ openssl req -pubkey -in foo.csr -noout -out pub.pem

# Alternatively, you can use:
$ openssl asn1parse -in foo.csr -strparse 27 -out tmp.der
$ openssl rsa -pubin -inform DER -in tmp.der -out pub.pem

# Extract the raw signature bytes:
$ openssl asn1parse -in foo.csr -strparse 338 -out sig.raw
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  70 cons: cont [ 3 ]        
Error in encoding
139935063934272:error:0D07209B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:too long:../crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c:91:
```

Ignore the error on the last one, this is because the extracted data is the raw signature bytes, it's not ASN.1 encoded. `openssl` still happily wrote it out to the file.

We now have the following files:

- `info.der`: the DER-encoded data that was signed
- `pub.pem`: the CSR requester's public key
- `sig.raw`: the signature included in the CSR

---

Let's verify the RSA signature (because that's what the signature algorithm says) using the public key and extract the original hash:

```
$ openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey pub.pem -in sig.raw -out hash.der
$ openssl asn1parse -i -in hash.der -inform DER
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:192E0909DABC7454006628AA3F7FB009AFA62A17A44908CAE5E166E528DCDD11
```

It didn't fail, so we already know the public key is the one that matches the private key used to sign the data.

The last section, the long `OCTET STRING` is the raw hash of the message as computed by the CSR requester:

```
192e0909dabc7454006628aa3f7fb009afa62a17a44908cae5e166e528dcdd11
```

---

Let's compute the `sha256` hash (once again: because the signature algorithm tells us to) of the `certificationRequestInfo`:

```
$ sha256sum info.der 
192e0909dabc7454006628aa3f7fb009afa62a17a44908cae5e166e528dcdd11  info.der
```

Yay! The hash is equal to the one extracted from the signature.

---

The hashes match and the signature was signed by the private key corresponding to the public key listed in the CSR. **This is a valid CSR**.

Done! See, I said it would be tedious.

Comment: Thanks a ton , Your explanation is amazing and made whole concept clear now.Thanks for the detailed steps and commands i can use this commands to understand expore more. Once again Thanks a lot.

Comment: No worries. As an exercise, you can look into how a certificate (as opposed to a CSR) is structured and verify its signature using the issuer's public key. It's a similar set of steps, just a different ASN.1 structure and of course the issuer's key come from the issuer's certificate (root or intermediate CA)

Comment: Thank you .. will do that . Meanwhile i have got a follow-up question / [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63907540/manually-created-signature-in-certificate-signing-request-is-not-matching-with-t) Please check if possible

Comment: I accidentally downvoted this answer, but I meant to upvote it.

Comment: @ericj: it happens, but within a certain amount of time you can undo the downvote (by clicking the downvote button again, or clicking on upvote)

Comment: @Mark, no, it says: You last voted on this answer Mar 1 at 18:39. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.