# Manually created signature in certificate signing request is not matching with the openssl req generated signature

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

- Created certificate signing request using following commands :

```
$ openssl genrsa -out test.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key test.key -subj "/CN=foo" -out foo.csr
```

- with the help of steps provided [@marc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63902570?noredirect=1) i have extracted 4 files from it :

  - info.der ( `openssl asn1parse -in foo.csr -strparse 4 -out info.der` )
  - pub.pem (`openssl req -pubkey -in foo.csr -noout -out pub.pem`)
  - hash.manual ( saved hex output of command `"sha256 info.der"`)
  - sig.raw (`openssl asn1parse -in foo.csr -strparse 338 -out sig.raw` )
- My understanding / doubt is , "Signature" mentioned in foo.csr is nothing but "encrypted ouptut" of the "hash.manual" with private key "test.key". so to validate my understanding i used

```
$ openssl rsautl -encrypt -in hash_manual -inkey test.key -out manual_signature
```

- Now when i perform diff on these two files they are not matching and hexdump -C confirms the sig.raw is matching the signature output mentioned in (openssl req -in csr --text).
- Please help in clarifying why manual_signature & sig.raw are not matching.

Comment: The inverse of `verify` is `sign`, not `encrypt`.

Comment: sign/signatue == rsa_encruption of (hash of ( data)) ?? this is my understanding . Please correct me if it is otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but it's encrypting with the private key (see [rsautl man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/rsautl.html)). Normal encryption encrypts with the public key. Because other algorithms do not work this way, we usually say `sign` and `verify`. Because `test.key` contains both private and public keys, `openssl` just uses the one it needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems:

- you need to use `sign` rather than `encrypt`. For RSA, `encrypt` is encryption with the public key but `sign` is encryption with the private key
- the output of `rsautl` is in the wrong format

The first is easy to fix, just use `-sign`.

The second is a bit more annoying, it is not just the `sha256` output being signed, it's an ASN.1 structure that looks like this:

```
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      
      0000 - dc 31 c9 99 51 ce 03 a2-aa 14 13 f1 c4 f6 3e ea   .1..Q.........>.
      0010 - 4f 87 a2 56 37 de 7f a7-c1 87 49 f0 43 c9 ba bb   O..V7.....I.C...
```

Where the final `OCTET STRING` field is the raw `sha256` hash.

The easiest way to generate this is to use `openssl dgst` to combine hashing and signature:

```
# Hash and sign the certificationRequestInfo
$ openssl dgst -sha256 -sign test.key info.der > manual_signature

# Compare to extracted sig.raw (no output means no diff)
$ diff manual_signature  sig.raw

# Verify both the extracted sig.raw and the manual_signature using the public key
$ openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey pub.pem -in sig.raw -asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      
      0000 - dc 31 c9 99 51 ce 03 a2-aa 14 13 f1 c4 f6 3e ea   .1..Q.........>.
      0010 - 4f 87 a2 56 37 de 7f a7-c1 87 49 f0 43 c9 ba bb   O..V7.....I.C...

$ openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey pub.pem -in manual_signature -asn1parse
    0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons:  SEQUENCE          
    4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :sha256
   15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim:   NULL              
   17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING      
      0000 - dc 31 c9 99 51 ce 03 a2-aa 14 13 f1 c4 f6 3e ea   .1..Q.........>.
      0010 - 4f 87 a2 56 37 de 7f a7-c1 87 49 f0 43 c9 ba bb   O..V7.....I.C...
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc . Understood the ease in using  `openssl dgst` in getting hash & signature done in one step.

Comment: strange behaviour when i use private key to encrypt the file using openssl rsautl 
`echo boo > boo`
`openssl rsautl -encrypt -in boo -inkey test.key -out boo.encrypted.withprivatekey`
`openssl rsautl -encrypt -in boo -pubin -inkey pub.pem -out boo.encrypted.withpublickey`
`diff boo.encrypted.withprivatekey boo.encrypted.withpublickey`
`- Binary files boo.encrypted.withprivatekey and boo.encrypted.withpublickey differ`

if rsautl uses public key to encrypt when i give private key as input then not sure why *boo.encrypted.withprivatekey* & *boo.encrypted.withpublickey* are different?

Comment: This is expected, RSA encryption uses random padding (default for rsautl is `PKCS#1 v1.5`) to be anywhere close to secure. Note that if you run the same encryption command multiple times you'll also end up with different results. See [this cryptography.se](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/why-are-rsa-ciphertexts-different-for-the-same-plaintext) question for details.